# Foursquare photo added via api not showing in venue detail

Tags: api, foursquare, endpoint

Need foursquare API experts help, I have a response of API endpoint "add photo" and it contains photo id which can be view able on API explorer but on web venue page no photo is showed not even in venue detail API call or venue/venue_id/photos

https://foursquare.com/developers/explore#req=photos%2F5d5c2af567339e0008d19915%3F
this is the photo uploaded, in the response there is a venue id which is not showing this photo in detail and web venue page.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing your parameters, API calls, or response data (I assume it's JSON), this is the best I can do as far as answering your question:

If you have the photos' `id`s, then you could try this endpoint:

```
GET https://api.foursquare.com/v2/photos/PHOTO_ID
```

That endpoint has a `venue` field in the response; check to see if it's pointing to the correct `venueId`.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).

Comment: I know but this how can I answer without having sufficient data?

Comment: Great job improving your answer!